# How to add badges to the icons of another app in android/kotlin

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin, mobile

I am creating a lock app, in which I want to add badges to the app icons of the locked apps. Can you please help me out with this.

Is it possible to add badges to other apps of my device via my app in kotlin

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it's not possible. As a matter of fact, it's not even guaranteed that you are able to do it to your own app icon. Setting badge icons is actually not a supported Android feature. Although many device manufacturers added their own custom implementation for that. See [Android Badge number on launcher icon for all mobile manufacturer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47250202/android-badge-number-on-launcher-icon-for-all-mobile-manufacturer) for example.

[Notification badges](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/badges) exists, but that is only for your own app, and actually is just an indication for having one or more notifications.